# PHP SQL - Search for match with same players

Tags: php, sql, arrays, mysqli

Good mornin'.
I've been tryin to make "something" that will compare matchup percentage but i'm stuck'd at searching for matches with 2 same players.

I've found something about AND OR parenthesis so here is my sql query

```
        $ccc = "SELECT * FROM zapasy WHERE (playerName01 = '".$player1."' OR playerName01 ='".$player2."') AND (playerName02 = '".$player2."' OR playerName02='".$player1."')";
        $result3 = $db->query($ccc);
        $ids = array();

        while ($row55 = $result3->fetch_assoc())
        {

$ids[] = $row55['winner'];


        }
```

But , the problem is whenever i try to get data , it gives me more indexes than actualy expected.
This is the result of printing array values after fetching.

```
Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 3 [2] => 4 [3] => 5 [4] => 6 )
```

As expected is only 2 3 4 as u can see in the DB sample here.
[db sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKhdl.png)

Anyone suggestions on what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to write this in MySQL uses tuples:

```
where (?, ?) in ( (playername01, playername02), (playername02, playername01) )
```

The `?` are for parameters.  That should be the way that you pass values into queries.

Comment: Thanks for advice , but the Mahesh's fix actualy works.

Comment: You should consider accepting an answer, whichever you prefer.  I think this one is simpler, but you are the OP and can accept whichever you like.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, can you give some examples of your answer, where we  have to put post variables in it,

Comment: @whoami where ($var1 , $var2) in ( ($p1_name, $p2_name), ($p2_name, $p1_name) )afaik

Answer (score 1):

You are doing wrong while using AND OR in where clause

```
$ccc = "SELECT * FROM zapasy WHERE (playerName01 = '".$player1."' AND playerName02 ='".$player2."') OR (playerName01 = '".$player2."' AND playerName02='".$player1."')";
```

Try this @Patrik Dano

Comment: I'm considering myself to be a dumbest person alive , thanks a lot !